# Determine if multiple boolean columns in a table are true for a record

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have five boolean columns in an entity and I'd like to know if two or more are true, is this possible to do this elegantly via linq?

Comment: You should look up how to ask a question on Stack Overflow (in particular, what exactly do you mean by _"I have five boolean columns"_).  You should show some code that gives the reader more context about your question.  However, the general approach to a general question like the one above would be "convert the trues to 1, and the falses to 0, then count things up"

Comment: Does following work?             object[] array = new object[]  { true, false, true, false, false };
            int results = array.Select(x => ((Boolean)x == true) ? 1 : 0).Sum();

Answer (score 0):

Where boolList is your list to check:

```
List<bool> trueList = boolList.Where(x => x == true).ToList();
return (trueList.Count >= 2) ? true : false;
```